# Words have value

Tags: word-property

"HELLO World" has value 12, while "Puzzles are great" has value 223.

What is the value of "Puzzling StackExchange" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "Puzzling StackExchange" will have a value of

> 24. (assuming StackExchange is one word).

The numbers are formed from

> the number of letters that have a "hole" in each word. For example, HELLO contains only 1 letter with a hole, which is O and world contains 2 (o and d). So its final value is 12.

Comment: Oooh you are so close! Have a closer look at "Puzzling"

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Right, I don't know how I missed that...

Comment: Now you got it! :)